# svg text does not keep the same size as graphic on different devices

Tags: php, svg, mobile-devices

I have created a calendar app in PHP with SVG where each month has a text row on top of the rectangle that represents the month. I developed it on a desktop PC, using the "monospace" font so that each day has the same pixel length.  This looks good on my PC screen, but when I watched the calendar on an iPad and a cell phone, the SVG text was suddenly longer than the rectangle and did not fit anymore. I tried other font faces, but the effect was always the same. In some cases, the text becomes smaller than the graphics, and in others bigger. I thought that by using SVG, the text and the graphic elements were all vector graphics and would scale the same way.
What can I do to make it work on all screens?
I could add screenshots, but it looks like it's not possible to add images here.
Here is the relevant part of the code

```
echo '<svg width="'.$svgW.'" height="'. $nM*($mHeight+$mOffset)+20 .'"  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">';   // total size

    echo '<rect x="0" y="'.$y0.'" width="'.$MonW -2 .'" height="'.$mHeight.'" style="fill:grey; stroke-width:2; stroke:rgb(0,0,0);" />';              // background for 1 month
    echo '<rect x="1" y="'.$y0.'" width="'.$MonW -3 .'" height="34" style="fill:WhiteSmoke; stroke-width:1; stroke:rgb(0,0,0)" />';       // background for dates & days of the month

    echo '<text x="14" y="' . $y0 +14 .'" font-size="15px" font-family="monospace" fill="black">'.sprintf('%02s',$mnr).' |</text>';       // month #
    echo '<text x="5" y="' . $y0 +30 .'" font-size="15px" font-family="monospace" fill="black">'.$year.'|</text>';                        // Year #
    echo '<text x="49" y="' . $y0 +14 .'" font-size="15px" font-family="monospace" fill="black">'.$allDates.'</text>';                    // all day #s
    echo '<text x="49" y="' . $y0 +30 .'" font-size="15px" font-family="monospace" fill="black">'.$dayNames.'</text>';                    // names of all days

    echo '<rect x="2" y= "' . $y0 +35 .'"  width="'.$aW.'" height="18 " style="fill:WhiteSmoke;" />';                             // 4 x gray fields for apartments
    echo '<rect x="2" y= "' . $y0 +54 .'"  width="'.$aW.'" height="18 " style="fill:WhiteSmoke;" />';
    echo '<rect x="2" y= "' . $y0 +73 .'"  width="'.$aW.'" height="18 " style="fill:WhiteSmoke;" />';
    echo '<rect x="2" y= "' . $y0 +92 .'"  width="'.$aW.'" height="18 " style="fill:WhiteSmoke;" />';

    echo '<text  x="18" y="' . $y0 +49 .'" font-size="15px" font-family="monospace" fill="black">A</text>';              // 4x names of the apartments
    echo '<text  x="18" y="' . $y0 +68 .'" font-size="15px" font-family="monospace" fill="black">B</text>';
    echo '<text  x="18" y="' . $y0 +87 .'" font-size="15px" font-family="monospace" fill="black">C</text>';
    echo '<text  x="18" y="' . $y0 +106 .'" font-size="15px" font-family="monospace" fill="black">D</text>';
    echo '<rect  x="'.$mStart.'" y= "' . $y0 +35 .'"  width="'.$ResW.'" height="18 " style="fill:rgb(0,255,0);" />';     // 4 green bars for reservations
    echo '<rect  x="'.$mStart.'" y= "' . $y0 +54 .'"  width="'.$ResW.'" height="18 " style="fill:rgb(0,255,0);" />';
    echo '<rect  x="'.$mStart.'" y= "' . $y0 +73 .'"  width="'.$ResW.'" height="18 " style="fill:rgb(0,255,0);" />';
    echo '<rect  x="'.$mStart.'" y= "' . $y0 +92 .'"  width="'.$ResW.'" height="18 " style="fill:rgb(0,255,0);" />';
echo '</svg>';
```

I have added the HTML code rendered in the browser (Chrome) to show the actual values

```html
<svg width="865" height="548" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="863.439" height="112" style="fill:grey; stroke-width:2; stroke:rgb(0,0,0);">
  </rect>
  <rect x="1" y="0" width="862.439" height="34" style="fill:WhiteSmoke; stroke-width:1; stroke:rgb(0,0,0)">
  </rect>
  <text x="14" y="14" font-size="15px" font-family="monospace" fill="black">10 |
  </text>
  <text x="5" y="30" font-size="15px" font-family="monospace" fill="black">2022|
  </text>
  <text x="49" y="14" font-size="15px" font-family="monospace" fill="black">
    01|02|03|04|05|06|07|08|09|10|11|12|13|14|15|16|17|18|19|20|21|22|23|24|25|26|27|28|29|30|31|
  </text>
  <text x="49" y="30" font-size="15px" font-family="monospace" fill="black">

    Sa|Su|Mo|Tu|We|Th|Fr|Sa|Su|Mo|Tu|We|Th|Fr|Sa|Su|Mo|Tu|We|Th|Fr|Sa|Su|Mo|Tu|We|Th|Fr|Sa|Su|Mo|
  </text>
  <rect x="2" y="35" width="42" height="18 " style="fill:WhiteSmoke;">
  </rect>
  <rect x="2" y="54" width="42" height="18 " style="fill:WhiteSmoke;">
  </rect>
  <rect x="2" y="73" width="42" height="18 " style="fill:WhiteSmoke;">
  </rect>
  <rect x="2" y="92" width="42" height="18 " style="fill:WhiteSmoke;">
  </rect>
  <text x="18" y="49" font-size="15px" font-family="monospace" fill="black">A</text>
  <text x="18" y="68" font-size="15px" font-family="monospace" fill="black">B</text>
  <text x="18" y="87" font-size="15px" font-family="monospace" fill="black">C</text>
  <text x="18" y="106" font-size="15px" font-family="monospace" fill="black">D</text>
  <rect x="46" y="35" width="817.439" height="18 " style="fill:rgb(0,255,0);"></rect>
  <rect x="46" y="54" width="817.439" height="18 " style="fill:rgb(0,255,0);"></rect>
  <rect x="46" y="73" width="817.439" height="18 " style="fill:rgb(0,255,0);"></rect>
  <rect x="46" y="92" width="817.439" height="18 " style="fill:rgb(0,255,0);"></rect>
  <rect x="0" y="132" width="837.07" height="112" style="fill:grey; stroke-width:2; stroke:rgb(0,0,0);"></rect>
  <rect x="1" y="132" width="836.07" height="34" style="fill:WhiteSmoke; stroke-width:1; stroke:rgb(0,0,0)"></rect>
  <text x="14" y="146" font-size="15px" font-family="monospace" fill="black">11 |
  </text>
  <text x="5" y="162" font-size="15px" font-family="monospace" fill="black">2022|</text>
  <text x="49" y="146" font-size="15px" font-family="monospace" fill="black">01|02|03|04|05|06|07|08|09|10|11|12|13|14|15|16|17|18|19|20|21|22|23|24|25|26|27|28|29|30|</text>
  <text x="49" y="162" font-size="15px" font-family="monospace" fill="black">Tu|We|Th|Fr|Sa|Su|Mo|Tu|We|Th|Fr|Sa|Su|Mo|Tu|We|Th|Fr|Sa|Su|Mo|Tu|We|Th|Fr|Sa|Su|Mo|Tu|We|</text>
  <rect x="2" y="167" width="42" height="18 " style="fill:WhiteSmoke;"></rect>
  <rect x="2" y="186" width="42" height="18 " style="fill:WhiteSmoke;"></rect>
  <rect x="2" y="205" width="42" height="18 " style="fill:WhiteSmoke;"></rect>
  <rect x="2" y="224" width="42" height="18 " style="fill:WhiteSmoke;"></rect><text x="18" y="181" font-size="15px" font-family="monospace" fill="black">A</text><text x="18" y="200" font-size="15px" font-family="monospace" fill="black">B</text><text x="18" y="219" font-size="15px" font-family="monospace" fill="black">C</text><text x="18" y="238" font-size="15px" font-family="monospace" fill="black">D</text>
  <rect x="46" y="167" width="791.07" height="18 " style="fill:rgb(0,255,0);"></rect>
  <rect x="46" y="186" width="791.07" height="18 " style="fill:rgb(0,255,0);"></rect>
  <rect x="46" y="205" width="791.07" height="18 " style="fill:rgb(0,255,0);"></rect>
  <rect x="46" y="224" width="791.07" height="18 " style="fill:rgb(0,255,0);"></rect>
  <rect x="0" y="264" width="863.439" height="112" style="fill:grey; stroke-width:2; stroke:rgb(0,0,0);"></rect>
  <rect x="1" y="264" width="862.439" height="34" style="fill:WhiteSmoke; stroke-width:1; stroke:rgb(0,0,0)"></rect><text x="14" y="278" font-size="15px" font-family="monospace" fill="black">12 |</text><text x="5" y="294" font-size="15px" font-family="monospace" fill="black">2022|</text><text x="49" y="278" font-size="15px" font-family="monospace" fill="black">01|02|03|04|05|06|07|08|09|10|11|12|13|14|15|16|17|18|19|20|21|22|23|24|25|26|27|28|29|30|31|</text><text x="49" y="294" font-size="15px" font-family="monospace" fill="black">Th|Fr|Sa|Su|Mo|Tu|We|Th|Fr|Sa|Su|Mo|Tu|We|Th|Fr|Sa|Su|Mo|Tu|We|Th|Fr|Sa|Su|Mo|Tu|We|Th|Fr|Sa|</text>
  <rect x="2" y="299" width="42" height="18 " style="fill:WhiteSmoke;"></rect>
  <rect x="2" y="318" width="42" height="18 " style="fill:WhiteSmoke;"></rect>
  <rect x="2" y="337" width="42" height="18 " style="fill:WhiteSmoke;"></rect>
  <rect x="2" y="356" width="42" height="18 " style="fill:WhiteSmoke;"></rect><text x="18" y="313" font-size="15px" font-family="monospace" fill="black">A</text><text x="18" y="332" font-size="15px" font-family="monospace" fill="black">B</text><text x="18" y="351" font-size="15px" font-family="monospace" fill="black">C</text><text x="18" y="370" font-size="15px" font-family="monospace" fill="black">D</text>
  <rect x="46" y="299" width="817.439" height="18 " style="fill:rgb(0,255,0);"></rect>
  <rect x="46" y="318" width="817.439" height="18 " style="fill:rgb(0,255,0);"></rect>
  <rect x="46" y="337" width="817.439" height="18 " style="fill:rgb(0,255,0);"></rect>
  <rect x="46" y="356" width="817.439" height="18 " style="fill:rgb(0,255,0);"></rect>
  <rect x="0" y="396" width="863.439" height="112" style="fill:grey; stroke-width:2; stroke:rgb(0,0,0);"></rect>
  <rect x="1" y="396" width="862.439" height="34" style="fill:WhiteSmoke; stroke-width:1; stroke:rgb(0,0,0)"></rect><text x="14" y="410" font-size="15px" font-family="monospace" fill="black">01 |</text><text x="5" y="426" font-size="15px" font-family="monospace" fill="black">2023|</text><text x="49" y="410" font-size="15px" font-family="monospace" fill="black">01|02|03|04|05|06|07|08|09|10|11|12|13|14|15|16|17|18|19|20|21|22|23|24|25|26|27|28|29|30|31|</text><text x="49" y="426" font-size="15px" font-family="monospace" fill="black">Su|Mo|Tu|We|Th|Fr|Sa|Su|Mo|Tu|We|Th|Fr|Sa|Su|Mo|Tu|We|Th|Fr|Sa|Su|Mo|Tu|We|Th|Fr|Sa|Su|Mo|Tu|</text>
  <rect x="2" y="431" width="42" height="18 " style="fill:WhiteSmoke;"></rect>
  <rect x="2" y="450" width="42" height="18 " style="fill:WhiteSmoke;"></rect>
  <rect x="2" y="469" width="42" height="18 " style="fill:WhiteSmoke;"></rect>
  <rect x="2" y="488" width="42" height="18 " style="fill:WhiteSmoke;"></rect><text x="18" y="445" font-size="15px" font-family="monospace" fill="black">A</text><text x="18" y="464" font-size="15px" font-family="monospace" fill="black">B</text><text x="18" y="483" font-size="15px" font-family="monospace" fill="black">C</text><text x="18" y="502" font-size="15px" font-family="monospace" fill="black">D</text>
  <rect x="46" y="431" width="817.439" height="18 " style="fill:rgb(0,255,0);"></rect>
  <rect x="46" y="450" width="817.439" height="18 " style="fill:rgb(0,255,0);"></rect>
  <rect x="46" y="469" width="817.439" height="18 " style="fill:rgb(0,255,0);"></rect>
  <rect x="46" y="488" width="817.439" height="18 " style="fill:rgb(0,255,0);"></rect>
  <rect x="46" y="54" width="817" height="18" style="fill:orange; stroke-width:1; stroke:grey"></rect>
  <rect x="46" y="186" width="458" height="18" style="fill:orange; stroke-width:1; stroke:grey"></rect>
  <rect x="46" y="35" width="817" height="18" style="fill:orange; stroke-width:1; stroke:grey"></rect>
  <rect x="46" y="167" width="791" height="18" style="fill:orange; stroke-width:1; stroke:grey"></rect>
  <rect x="46" y="299" width="817" height="18" style="fill:orange; stroke-width:1; stroke:grey"></rect>
  <rect x="46" y="431" width="817" height="18" style="fill:orange; stroke-width:1; stroke:grey"></rect>
  <rect x="301" y="92" width="562" height="18" style="fill:orange; stroke-width:1; stroke:grey"></rect>
  <rect x="46" y="224" width="62" height="18" style="fill:orange; stroke-width:1; stroke:grey"></rect>
  <rect x="512" y="73" width="308" height="18" style="fill:orange; stroke-width:1; stroke:grey"></rect>
  <rect x="828" y="73" width="35" height="18" style="fill:orange; stroke-width:1; stroke:grey"></rect>
  <rect x="46" y="205" width="88" height="18" style="fill:orange; stroke-width:1; stroke:grey"></rect>
  <rect x="116" y="224" width="71" height="18" style="fill:orange; stroke-width:1; stroke:grey"></rect>
  <rect x="380" y="205" width="457" height="18" style="fill:orange; stroke-width:1; stroke:grey"></rect>
  <rect x="46" y="337" width="352" height="18" style="fill:orange; stroke-width:1; stroke:grey"></rect>
  <rect x="380" y="224" width="457" height="18" style="fill:orange; stroke-width:1; stroke:grey"></rect>
  <rect x="46" y="356" width="817" height="18" style="fill:orange; stroke-width:1; stroke:grey"></rect>
  <rect x="46" y="488" width="352" height="18" style="fill:orange; stroke-width:1; stroke:grey"></rect>
  <rect x="512" y="186" width="18" height="18" style="fill:yellow; stroke-width:1; stroke:grey"></rect>
  <rect x="564" y="186" width="273" height="18" style="fill:orange; stroke-width:1; stroke:grey"></rect>
  <rect x="46" y="318" width="817" height="18" style="fill:orange; stroke-width:1; stroke:grey"></rect>
  <rect x="46" y="450" width="36" height="18" style="fill:orange; stroke-width:1; stroke:grey"></rect>
  <rect x="406" y="337" width="124" height="18" style="fill:orange; stroke-width:1; stroke:grey"></rect>
  <rect x="301" y="450" width="71" height="18" style="fill:orange; stroke-width:1; stroke:grey"></rect>
  <rect x="327" y="469" width="536" height="18" style="fill:orange; stroke-width:1; stroke:grey"></rect>
  <rect x="380" y="450" width="361" height="18" style="fill:orange; stroke-width:1; stroke:grey"></rect>
  <rect x="406" y="488" width="457" height="18" style="fill:orange; stroke-width:1; stroke:grey"></rect>
  <rect x="749" y="450" width="114" height="18" style="fill:orange; stroke-width:1; stroke:grey"></rect>
</svg>
```

Comment: monospace is not a specific font. Try picking an actual font that all devices have.

Comment: @Robert Longson
It may not seem so, but it is a specific font. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospace_(typeface).
Anyway, I found a workaround that avoids this problem.
Should I just delete the question (which is a real problem anyway and may have a real solution)? 
The workaround is to not use a long string with a chain of all the day numbers and names, but a series of short texts for each day, so the distortion remains small enough to be virtually invisible. This makes the HTML code longer as there are more lines with "<text>" but there is nearly no difference on the PHP level. Tnx

Comment: Nope, See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-family) where monospace is listed as: "generic family name only" the article goes on to tell you what that means in practice.